# Confusion on the proofs of convolution theorem of Fourier Transform.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-transform

The convolution theorem of Fourier transform is stated as follows:

> Define $h(x):=f(x)*g(x)$, then we have $$\hat{h}(k)=\hat{f}(k)\hat{g}(k).$$

I have a confusion of the proofs of this theorem. Most proofs go in the following way:

Define $h(x):=f(x)*g(x)$.  By definition, we have $$\hat{h}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)e^{-ikx}dx.$$
Then, plugging in the integral expression of $f*g$ into the above integral yields us
\begin{align*}
\hat{h}(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)e^{-ikx}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)ds\Big)e^{-ikx}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}dsdx.\ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{align*}

Then, most proofs directly change integral order in the question $(*)$, so that

\begin{align*}
\hat{h}(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}dsdx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}dxds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)e^{-ikx}dx\Big)g(s)ds.
\end{align*}

What remains is standard: note that by the shifting property, the inner integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)e^{-ikx}dx=\hat{f}(k)e^{-iks},$$ and thus
\begin{align*}
\hat{h}(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)e^{-ikx}dx\Big)g(s)ds\\
&=\hat{f}(k)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(s)e^{-iks}ds\\
&=\hat{f}(k)\hat{g}(k),
\end{align*}
where the last equality was obtained by definition. The proof is concluded.

---

However, why could we change the integral order of (*) in the first place? Don't we need Fubini? I tried to use Fubini as follows: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}|dsdx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)|dsdx$$ but I do not know how to proceed further. I had expected that I can split the integral so that I would have two $L^{1}-$norm, but since the first integral is $ds$, I could not split the integral..

Do we directly assume the function is nice enough so that we can interchange the integral order? If so, what type of functions do we assume?

Thank you!

Comment: In the integral where you have the absolute values of the functions you can change the order of integration by using Tonelli's theorem. Whenever you have positive measurable functions you change the order of integration, you dont necessarily need integrability.

Comment: @dem0nakos oh okay.. yeah.. I forgot this. so as long as we are in $L^{1}$, we are good, right?

Comment: @dem0nakos so we have \begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}|dsdx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)|dsdx&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)|dxds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(|g(s)|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)|dx\Big)ds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(|f(x-s)\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})})dx\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}<\infty,
\end{align*} right? The Tonelli was applied to the third equality

Comment: Your proof is right. Although let point out again that you can use Tonelli theorem without being in $L^1$. The fact that both functions are in $L^1$ allows you to use Fubini without the absolute values.

Comment: @dem0nakos  I think I got what you meant. I checked the Fubini-Tonelli again from wikipedia. So basically since $f,g\in L^{1}$, the integral of absolute value in the order $dxds$ is finite (as showed above), so I can directly apply Fubini-Tonelli to change the order of the integration.

Comment: No you need to use Tonelli's theorem first to check if your function in the product space ( i.e. $h(x,s)$ in our situation ) is integrable with respect to the product measure and then use Fubini to change the order without the absolute values. h(x,s) is measurable in the product space $L^1 \times L^1$.

Comment: @dem0nakos got you. Thanks for the patience and great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ***demonakos***' help, it turned out that as long as $f,g\in L^{1}$, the integral order can be interchanged.

The proof is as follows: note that by Tonelli's theorem (in the third equality),
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}|dsdx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)|dsdx&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)g(s)|dxds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(|g(s)|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x-s)|dx\Big)ds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(|f(x-s)\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})})dx\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}\|g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}<\infty,
\end{align*}
the $L^{1}-$norm is finite since $f$ and $g$ were hypothesized to be in $L^{1}$.

Hence, it follows from Fubini's Theorem that we can interchange integration order in $(*)$. That is
\begin{align*}
\hat{h}(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}dsdx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)g(s)e^{-ikx}dxds\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-s)e^{-ikx}dx\Big)g(s)ds.
\end{align*}

---

In fact, one could see the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function).

Instead of using Tonelli and Fubini seperately, one could directly check $\int\int|f(x-s)g(s)|dxds<\infty$ as above, and using Fubini-Tonelli to directly conclude that the integral order can be interchanged.

Although equivalent, there is still a little bit difference.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the order of integration:
$ikx=ik(x-s)+iks$  and $u=x-s$ so $h(k)=\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(u)e^{-iku}g(s)e^{-iks}dsdu$$=\hat{f}(k)\hat{g}(k)$.

Comment: I do not think this works, since $u$ contains $s$ which has already been integrated, so that this change of variable may not make sense.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical  You may be right.  Implicitly it may require the change in order of integration.